# dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, x86

When I change the platform target to x86 my console application gives this error.

> D:\notes\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0>dotnet
> ConsoleApp1.dll Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException:
> Could not load file or assembly
> 'D:\notes\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.dll'.
> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. File
> name:
> 'D:\notes\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp1.dll'

[image]

[image]

I want to build my code in x86 and it gives an error.

Comment: What about the Linux system? How to change Path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the x86 edition of dotnet, its typical location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe`.

[Breaking change: x86 host path on 64-bit Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/deployment/7.0/x86-host-path)